# Verify Elavon Converge payment gateway Api credential in php

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I am using **Elavon Converge** payment gateway.

I want to verify the merchant account credential (like merchant_id, user_id, pin) before submit the card details.

Here is my code :

```
$url = 'https://demo.myvirtualmerchant.com/VirtualMerchantDemo/process.do'; 
$fields = array(
'ssl_merchant_id'=>'XXXXXXXX',
'ssl_user_id'=>'XXXX',
'ssl_pin'=>'XXXXXXX',
'ssl_first_name'=>'Heapdrip',
'ssl_last_name'=>'Heap',
'ssl_show_form'=>'false',
'ssl_result_format'=>'html',
'ssl_test_mode'=>'false',
'ssl_receipt_apprvl_method'=>'redg',
'ssl_receipt_decl_method'=>'REDG', 
'ssl_receipt_decl_get_url'=>'RETURN URL AFTER PAYMENT DECLINED',
'ssl_error_url'=>'RETURN URL AFTER PAYMENT ERROR',
'ssl_receipt_apprvl_get_url'=>'RETURN URL AFTER PAYMENT APPROVAL',
'ssl_transaction_type'=>'ccsale',
'ssl_amount'=>'5000',
'ssl_card_number'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
'ssl_exp_date'=>'122022',
'ssl_cvv2cvc2_indicator'=>1,
'ssl_cvv2cvc2'=>123
);
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This is direct payment method but I want to check the merchant_id, user_id and pin are correct or not.

Comment: And we should do what? Write code for you?

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service. Can you show us what code you've written and explain what your specific issue is?

Comment: Absolutely not I google it a lot but didn't find any solution. I already integrate the gateway but first i want to check the credentials.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. The question you have posted does not fall in the scope of questions discussed here. Please refer to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to see what kind of questions you can ask here. Regards.

Comment: means no 1 can help me. Thanks I will google it again try to find solution myself.

Comment: Anyone wrote code in ios?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you post to the process.do url and the payment form comes up then the credentials are validated as the form does not pull if they don't.